# Multiple values in a single data-field?

Tags: java, object

I have created the class:

```
public playlists(int ID, String nam, int lengt, int movi) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
playlistID = ID;
name = nam;
length = lengt;
movieID = movi;
}
```

The data-field `movieID` of object `playlists` needs to store multiple values. I was wondering how I could do this.

Comment: You can use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: ArrayList,map,Set,array depending on what you need

Comment: Google is a hell of a tool.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments already say: Use an ArrayList or an Array
Use ArrayList to store as many objects as you wish (theoretically)
Use Array if you know the exact number ob objects you want to store

```
ArrayList<Integer> musicIDs= new ArrayList();


public playlists(int ID, String nam, int lengt, int movi) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    playlistID = ID;
    name = nam;
    length = lengt;
    movieIDs.add(movi);
}
```

My codeblock just makes sense if you add some musicids later on to this class.
If you create a new instance of this class and still want all musicids you should use static:

```
static ArrayList<Integer>...
```

EDIT:

Thats how i would do it :

```
    public class Main()
{
    private Playlist playlist = new Playlist(); 

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        MovieInf omi = new MovieInfo(1,"a",2,3);
        playlist.add(mi);
        mi = new MovieInfo(2,"b",3,4);
        playlist.add(mi);
            System.out.println(Playlist.getSizeOfList()); // prints "2"

    }

}

public class MovieInfo()
{
    private int ID,length,movi;
    private String name;

    public MovieInfo(int ID, String nam, int lengt, int movi) {
        this.ID= ID;
        this.name= name;
        this.length= length;
        this.movi= movi;
    }

}

public class Playlist()

{

    private ArrayList<MovieInfo> movies = new ArrayList();

    public void add(MovieInfo mi)
    {
        movies.add(mi);
    }

    public int getSizeOfList()
    {
        return movies.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you mind providing an example an object being created?

Comment: like that ? @SWAGYOLODINOSAURSWAG